# Chrome rendering color incorrectly, but not Safari or Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors

I'm coding a website as a little project and I ran across something a weird when testing in Chrome on Mac OS X.  I have a div as a header where I set the background color to #FF9540.  Most times it renders as RGB (255, 149, 64) which is right.  On some pages though, it renders as RGB (245, 152, 33).  I noticed when it does render correctly, it first renders RGB (245, 152, 33) then switches to RGB (255, 149, 64) when it loads.  This problem does not exist in Safari or Firefox.  I've included two pictures showing the div is styled the same hex color, but it is rendered as two different colors.

Also, uploading the images here gives different RGB values than I see when I load the images on my computer.

[image: Should be RGB(255, 149, 64)]
[image: Should be RGB(245, 152, 33)]

Comment: Have you tried setting the color value as RGB instead of hex?

Answer (score -1):

Just fixed this thanks to [this guide](http://www.brilliantthinking.net/2012/08/06/how-to-fix-screen-colour-changes-in-mountain-lion-osx/)(DEAD LINK).

Simply go into Disk Utility, select your disk and repair permissions. When it's done restart Chrome and you should see the difference.

*This worked for me using Chrome 27.0.1453.116 on OSX 10.8.4*